# SAS Labels are missing and are greyed out in column properties

Tags: properties, dataset, sas, label

We have several datasets which are created by reading in csv files. Some macros are run to create data sets. Until recently the labels for column were being displayed when you hove over the column header. However the labels are now blank and you cannot edit them unter column properties.

We are using SAS Enterpise Guide 4.3. Looking into the macros I cannot see anything which remnoves the labels (eg. attrib _ all _ label=' ')

Am I missing something more fundemental?

Comment: What changed around the time it stopped working? E.g. change in user rights, SAS update, changes to your code... ?

Comment: How are the CSV files read in PROC IMPORT or Data Step?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for code that originally created labels to begin with, not code that cleared them.

If you use File->Import Data in EG, you enter a wizard to

1) specify data

2) select data source

3) define field attributes

4) advanced options

Step 3 gives you an opportunity to rename fields and create labels that differ from the field names. If you don't specify changes in this screen, no label statements will be created in the code at all.

HTH,
pT